# Approximating the error of maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, error, approximation

I have a log likelihood function of a model and I want to find $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ which maximize the log likelihood. Since the log lik function is quite complex, I decided to use Nelder-Mead algorithm from `scipy` module. What I would like to do now is to estimate the errors on $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ retrieved by Nelder-Mead algorithm.

How to do it **without** calculating the Hessian of the function?

EDIT: I found a way to approximate the Hessian (using [numdifftools.core.Hessian](https://numdifftools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/numdifftools.core.Hessian.html)) but I'm not sure how much can I rely on it.

EDIT 2: In some cases I manage to use the approximated Hessian (from `numdifftools`) but in other cases, it doesn't work. And it seems like there is a number precision problem. So I'm still looking for a solution with which I can efficiently asses the approximation error without using Hessian or an implementation of a Hessian approximation which works good in high number precision.

Comment: Does the data follow some specific distribution?

Comment: Yes, it follows a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Have you considered bootstrapping?

Comment: @Denziloe I haven't. Mostly because of the reason it would not give me one error value for each parameter and also it would depend on the number of samples I choose, right? The thing is that I repeat the process of inferring mean and variance thousands of times (for many subsets of my given data set) and I would like to have a more convenient way of getting the error rather than sampling.

Comment: Sure, if optimisation is important then it makes sense to rule out bootstrapping. Choosing the number of samples isn't an issue though, you just need to choose "enough". The more the better but after a moderate number the answer should start to converge. And you'd get errors for each parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Complicated likelihood or not, I suggest taking advantage of auto-differentiation tools to compute Jacobians and hessians.

In Python, there is the autograd library. This will give you exact hessians, and jacobian vectors for better convergence. See my notes here on using autograd for MLEs: https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/PyDataNY_2019_tutorial/tree/master/full_notebooks

And more notes here: https://rlhick.people.wm.edu/posts/mle-autograd.html

Answer (score 0):

You could assume that the real mean and variance are μ* and σ<sup>2</sup>* respectively, and use the formulas you use to estimate the estimators μ and σ<sup>2</sup> (which are themselves stochastic variables, since they depend on your sampled values which are stochastic values) to calculate the variances of μ and σ<sup>2</sup> as functions of the variance in the sampled values, i.e. σ<sup>2</sup>*.

Since you don't know σ<sup>2</sup>* , you could assume that σ<sup>2</sup> ≈ σ<sup>2</sup>* and plug in the value for σ<sup>2</sup> instead of σ<sup>2</sup>* when evaluating the expressions for the variances of μ and σ<sup>2</sup>. The square root of those variances, i.e. the standard deviations of the estimators, give you an indication of the error of the estimators.